# How to perform image segmentation on white lines in a green field/grassy field

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, straight-line-detection

As the title states I'm attempting to do image segmentation in hopes of doing 'lane' detection. Here is a sample image I want to test on. [image]

Here's my first coding attempt for what I tried that I found online essentially.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2
def image_seg_watershed():
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_file,img_file_list[0]))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(thresh)
    plt.show()
```

This is the output. [image]

Kinda close, but not what I wanted. Any tips or helpful advice?

Comment: why do you call this function watershed if you're just applying a global threshold?

Comment: Forgot to change the name. Tried watershed and it didn't work lol, so I just rewrote the method and never changed the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential approach is color segmentation using [`cv2.inRange()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html). With the assumption that the desired lines are white, we can isolate pixels in this color range. Here's the main idea

- Convert image to HSV format since its easier to represent color
- Perform color segmentation using lower/upper threshold
- Filter using contour area to remove small particles

---

We convert the image to HSV format since its easier to represent color than RBG or BGR format. Then we create a lower/upper threshold to detect white pixels and  create a mask using `cv2.inRange()`

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
result = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0,0,200])
upper = np.array([179, 77, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(result,result, mask=mask)
```

Note there are small particles of noise so the next step is to remove some of it. There are several approaches we can take here. One is to use [morphological operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) to erode/dilate the image. Another approach is to find contours and filter using contour area to ignore the small particles. I'll use the latter approach. We use a minimum threshold area to filter out particles and fill them in with black using `cv2.drawContours()`. Here's the result

[image]

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 1:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)
```

---

Full code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
result = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0,0,200])
upper = np.array([179, 77, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(result,result, mask=mask)

cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 1:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

You can use a color threshold script to find the lower/upper HSV boundaries

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('HMin','image',0,179,nothing) # Hue is from 0-179 for Opencv
cv2.createTrackbar('SMin','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMin','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('HMax','image',0,179,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMax','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMax','image',0,255,nothing)

# Set default value for MAX HSV trackbars.
cv2.setTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image', 179)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image', 255)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image', 255)

# Initialize to check if HSV min/max value changes
hMin = sMin = vMin = hMax = sMax = vMax = 0
phMin = psMin = pvMin = phMax = psMax = pvMax = 0

img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
output = img
waitTime = 33

while(1):

    # get current positions of all trackbars
    hMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMin','image')
    sMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMin','image')
    vMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMin','image')

    hMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMax','image')
    sMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMax','image')
    vMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMax','image')

    # Set minimum and max HSV values to display
    lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
    upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])

    # Create HSV Image and threshold into a range.
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)

    # Print if there is a change in HSV value
    if( (phMin != hMin) | (psMin != sMin) | (pvMin != vMin) | (phMax != hMax) | (psMax != sMax) | (pvMax != vMax) ):
        print("(hMin = %d , sMin = %d, vMin = %d), (hMax = %d , sMax = %d, vMax = %d)" % (hMin , sMin , vMin, hMax, sMax , vMax))
        phMin = hMin
        psMin = sMin
        pvMin = vMin
        phMax = hMax
        psMax = sMax
        pvMax = vMax

    # Display output image
    cv2.imshow('image',output)

    # Wait longer to prevent freeze for videos.
    if cv2.waitKey(waitTime) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: damn that's awesome. Thanks for the advice. I'll def try this out when I have the time tomorrow. Thank you!